# Select com transição na alteração com onchange

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Como adicionar um efeito de transição (*fade*) em um `select` com `onchange`, que quando o objeto `<div>` for alterado o mesmo ocorra uma transição?
Abaixo segue um *print* da tabela que foi feita:

[image: Print Tabela]

E este é o script:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Isto é a seleção de planos, basta adicionar em qualquer lugar para que o usuario selecione o plano 
Atenção! Em value coloque o valor do plano -->

<p> 
<select name="select" onchange="document.getElementById('selecionado').innerHTML = 'R$ ' + this.value;">  
     <option value="nenhum|" selected="selected">Selecione:</option>  
    <option value="10,00">Mensal</option>
    <option value="11,00">Trimestral</option>  
    <option value="12,00">Semestral</option>
    <option value="13,00">Anual</option>  
  </select>  
</p>  

<p id="selecionado">
    O valor padrão
</p>   <!-- Acrescente este código aonde você quer que o texto seja trocado -->

<!-- Como criar uma outra seleção:

Basta trocar o nome em:
<select name="select" onchange="document.getElementById('selecionado').innerHTML = 'R$ ' + this.value;">  
Este código você troca esta parte que estará em maiusculo:
<select name="select" onchange="document.getElementById('TROCAR ESTA PALAVRA PARA UMA OUTRA QUALQUER').innerHTML = 'R$ ' + this.value;"> 
E aí coloque o código de seleção:
<p id="selecionado"></p> 
Troque a palavra que "selecionado" para o mesmo que você colocou no primeiro código.
-->
```

Quero que quando a pessoa alterar o ciclo de pagamento no `select`, ele mude o preço só que com um *fade*, porque do jeito que está, ele muda na hora. Eu quero tipo um *fade* [neste exemplo](http://www.kinghost.com.br/planos): ao clicar para alterar ocorre um *fade* ( transição ) nos preços, e não apenas muda.

Só que na minha tabela não vai ser um único `select`, ele vai ter vários cada plano com um, como mostrado na imagem acima.

Comment: Alexandre, pode usar-se Mootools, jQUery ou outra biblioteca?

Comment: Sim, o importante é que funcione. :D

Comment: Oi, Alexandre, bem-vindo ao SOPT :) Editei sua pergunta para melhorar a formatação, confira o [guia do markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Por favor, coloque sempre o código com problemas aqui mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado @brasofilo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você precisa é de uma animação. No exmplo em baixo uso jQuery [animate](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) e posso colocar daqui a pouco outra variante com MooTools. Deixo comentários no código.

Exemplo:

```
mostrador.animate({
    opacity: 0           // mudar a opacidade para 0 = invisivel
}, 200, function () {    // chamar a função que corre quando o 1o animate acabar
    mostrador.html(val); // enquanto está invisivel mudar o valor
    mostrador.animate({
        opacity: 1      // mudar para visivel
    }, 200)             // velocidade = 200 milisegundos
})
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BN3P/)

Teste neste exemplo mudar o select.

Para aplicar isto ao seu código precisa de fazer algumas alterações:

- se quer usar vários selects eu mudei para ter uma div à volta de cada select para facilitar encontrar o elemento que mostra o preço. Pode fazer-se de outras maneiras mas é bom não customizar demais.
- retirei o ID do `<p id="selecionado">` pois os ID's têm de ser únicos, mudei para uma classe: `<p class="selecionado">`
- retirei o script dentro do HTML, é má prática e usei em vez disso o `$('select.selectPreco').on('change', function () {`

Comment: Mais o problema é que eu não entendo muito de javascript, meu forte é CSS. Você poderia implementar essa função no script que deixei para download a cima? #porfavor

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, é isto que quer: http://jsfiddle.net/7BN3P/ ?

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sergio, você me ajudou também!

Comment: Minha internet não ajuda, não consigo acessar o site, está lenta...

Comment: Sim sim, muitoooooooooo obrigadoooooooooooooooo!!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, está tarde para mim, tenho de ir dormir. Se precisar de mais ajuda vou dar uma olhada aqui amanhã cedo. Se fôr isto que pretende pode também aceitar a resposta. Porém há 1001 maneiras de fazer isto. Eu deixei uma delas, como exemplo.

Comment: Nossa aqui no brasil agora que é 18:57
Muito obrigado, vou testar e volto aqui, caramba, brigadão mesmo, você é um gênio!

Comment: @Sergio você poderia adicionar um novo select? pois aqui http://jsfiddle.net/7BN3P/ só possui um, com dois eu poderia seguir a estrutura do seu código e fazer quantos selects eu quisesse sem problemas. :D

Comment: Abaixo segue o link do modelo da minha tabela
http://testetabela.esy.es/

Comment: @Sergio eu tentei aqui e não consegui deixar como o 1° e 3° plano, olha aí http://testetabela.esy.es/ eu queria que ficasse como nos planos: Basic e Plus, :/

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, estás por ai?

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, afinal você já tinha classes possiveis de usar. Na próxima vêz coloque o seu código na pergunta, vai ter uma resposta melhor e mais rápida! Deixo aqui o código re-adaptado. Se quiser podemos ter um chat sobre isto para aprender melhor sem termos de colocar 1001 comentários aqui. Mas dê uma olhada para o código a ver se compreende: __http://jsfiddle.net/4n87D/__

Comment: Me adiciona no skype por favor: alexandre.drs
Desculpe acabei de acordar, o fuso horário do brasil é muito dieferente do seu, rsrsrs, e muito obrigado pela sua paciência! :D....
Sim é isto mesmo que queria, cara nem sei como agradecer, você é um gênio!

Comment: @AlexandreLopes, podemos usar chat aqui no SO. __[clicke aqui](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13779/discussion-between-dois-utilizadores?tab=general)__.

Comment: @Sergio, você poderia me ajudar nesse tópico?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14543/como-integrar-um-select-em-uma-tabela
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O site mencionado como exemplo usar o seguinte script (adaptado):

```
.find('.price-value').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).html('R$ ' + price_discount_split[0] +',<sup class="sup">' + 
    price_discount_split[1] + '</sup><span class="span">/mês</span>').fadeIn();
})
```

Então se você quiser usar o mesmo efeito você pode usar o [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) + [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout) do jQuery.

1:

```
.find('.price-value').fadeOut(
```

desaparece com o valor antigo.

2:

```
'fast'
```

O primeiro parâmetro diz o tempo de duração do efeito.

3:

```
function(){
    $(this).html('R$ ' + price_discount_split[0] +',<sup class="sup">' + 
    price_discount_split[1] + '</sup><span class="span">/mês</span>').fadeIn();
}
```

O segundo parâmetro é um handler de uma função para ser executado ao completar o fadeOut do preço antigo.

É executado então o fadeIn do próprio elemento, mostrando-o de novo, mas alterando o seu conteúdo (`.html()`) - é colocado o novo preço:

```
 $(this).html('R$ ' + novoPreco).fadeIn()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela colaboração, também vou testar seu exemplo.

Comment: você poderia hospedar seu exemplo para que eu possa ver, como eu disse eu não entendo muito de javascript.

Comment: André eu já tentei usar o fadeIn e Out do jQuery, porém eles não tem uma boa transição para textos, e eu quero é para textos... Exatamente como o Sergio fez.